# df.plot.density() returns an empty plot despite values actually being there

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have this data set

```
                    WSPD   GST   WD WVHT  DPD  APD MWD   BAR  ATMP  WTMP
Date                                                                      
2005-06-06 03:00:00  8.2   9.8   86  NaN  NaN  NaN  77  1011.1  28.8    29
2005-06-06 04:00:00  9.4  11.2   96  NaN  NaN  NaN  79  1011.6    29    29
2005-06-06 05:00:00  9.4  10.9  103  NaN  NaN  NaN  78  1011.6    29  28.9
2005-06-06 06:00:00  7.5     9  114  NaN  NaN  NaN  84  1011.4  27.7  28.9
2005-06-06 07:00:00    7  10.4  118  NaN  NaN  NaN  85  1011.1  25.4  28.9
```

I am attempting to do a probability density plot for the column with WVHT. However, when I type:

```
df['WVHT'].plot.density()
```

I receive an empty plot despite the column actually having values. Please note this is just a sample of the data.

Comment: What kind of data does it have? I can see only NaNs there.

Comment: The issue could be with data as well. Is it possible for you to upload and share a small part of real data?

Comment: It has significant wave height data in meters. This part is just the head of the data set.

Comment: It has significant wave height data in meters. This part is just the head of the data set.

Comment: WSPD   GST  WD  WVHT   DPD   APD  MWD     BAR  ATMP  WTMP
Date                                                                         
2015-12-31 18:50:00  9.6  11.2  77  2.05  7.69  5.65  107  1013.3  27.9  27.9
2015-12-31 19:50:00  9.9  12.2  73  2.23    10   5.6  109  1012.6  27.9  27.9
2015-12-31 20:50:00  8.9  10.3  80  2.31  7.14  5.62   93  1012.5    28  27.9
2015-12-31 21:50:00  8.9  10.5  73  2.41  8.33  5.74  107  1012.6    28  27.9
2015-12-31 22:50:00  8.7  10.1  67  2.14  7.14   5.5  103  1013.1  27.9  27.9

Comment: My apologies for how messy it looks but I am not sure how to get it in a better form.

Comment: Your data is bad.  This works for me with and without `np.nan` for pandas version 0.18 and 0.20.  Probably can't help further without you providing a good way to replicate the data that is giving you the problem.